# Java Spring form tag question

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using JSPs, and this is my contacts.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3.0 MVC series: Contact manager</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Contact Manager</h2>
<form:form method="post" action="addContact.html">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td> // LABEL
            <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="lastName">Email</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="lastName">Telephone</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="telephone" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Add Contact"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

My questions is, that when i change `form:label path="firstName"` into `form:label path="firstname"`, why tomcat starts throwing errors? Doesn't the model only need the input path, since the value inside input path, is the value it will use?

EDIT:

**should i even use the `form:label tag` , why is it used?**

Comment: The value of using labels is that they allow the user to click on the label to select the control to which the label is attached (via the label's "for" attribute).

Comment: The form:label tag needs a path attribute so that it can generate the "for" attribute of the label tag.

Comment: You should always use labels; they make your code more accessible to screen readers and other alternative user agents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because `firstName` is either used literally, or is translated into the method `getFirstName()`.

Either way, the capitalization matters when the lookup is performed.

---

For your question on whether or not you need the `path` in the label: If you provide the path, then the label will know which input it belongs to. In HTML, that allows you to click on the label and have the input field gain focus. I assume the output HTML for your code is something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td><label for="firstName"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="firstName"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: But should i use the `form:label` tag anyways, when it does not matter if it is there, or it is not?

Comment: I am wondering, why should i use the `form:label` tag, when it is not used anywhere?

Comment: I assume the output is a `<label>`, so if you don't want that, then don't use it. I'm not quite sure what the other option is? You either want a label or you don't. It's not required.

Comment: Yes I can have label and I can't, but my initial question was this: Why does my label need a path?

Comment: Sorry, but it was not clear that was your original question. If you provide the path, then the label will know which input it belongs to. In HTML, that allows you to click on the label and have the input field gain focus. I assume the output HTML for your code is something like this: `<td><label for="firstName"></td><td><input type="text" id="firstName"></td>`

Comment: Oh great, yeah i was confused and tried to ask many questions in same time, but thanks for your answer, that was exactly what i wanted to know!